# Find Opportunity Recordtype Name

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a custom Button on my Opportunity Page Layout which redirects to a visual force page where I have to send mail to client depending on the Opportunity Record Type name. Now how to access the current record's recordtype name from my page controller ?

Answer (score 2):

Record Type Name can be queried using SOQL.

```
Id oppId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');

List<Opportunity> oppList = [Select Id, Name, RecordType.Name from Opportunity where Id =: oppId];
if(oppList.size() > 0){
    System.debug('###'+oppList[0].RecordType.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for RecordType information without using any SOQLs for Case. Depending of entry data, map can be reversed and built as (RecordTypeName:RecordTypeID).

```
List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> caseRecordTypeInfo = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Case').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();
Map<id,String> caseRecordMap = new Map<id,String>();
for(Schema.RecordTypeInfo rtInfo: caseRecordTypeInfo)
{
    caseRecordMap.put(rtInfo.getRecordTypeId(),rtInfo.getName());
}
caseRecordMap.get(recordTypeID);  //returns RecordTypeName
```

Or if you already selecting your object you can just add RecordTypeId and RecordType.Name to your SOQL query.